# Do other buildings in City Story also generate income?

Tags: city-story

I'm playing City Story on the iPad and I'm left wondering whether those two Empire State Buildings of mine actually generate any income, or is this restricted to making things in the Factories?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only income that non-factory buildings generate is when somebody comes by and cleans them for you. The other buildings are split into ones that increase your population and those that increase your happiness. Since neither stat seems to affect gameplay (as of when I tried the game) you just want to make sure you have enough buildings so that your occasional visitors have some buildings to clean. Other players may feel more inclined to clean your city if you have nice buildings or use them in an artistic manner.